# C Macros function definition syntax question

Tags: c, macros

I've been looking through a program called [hickit](https://github.com/lh3/hickit), and at one point (count.c, function starts at line 105), and they call a macros function (kavl_insert) from the Klib library as follows:

```
static void hk_count_nei2_core(int32_t n_pairs, struct cnt_nei2_aux *a, int r1, int r2)
{
    struct cnt_nei2_aux *root = 0;
    int32_t i, j, left;
    unsigned cl;
    left = 0;
    kavl_insert(nei2, &root, &a[0], 0);
...
```

Looking at the Klib library (more specifically, in [kavl.h](https://github.com/attractivechaos/klib/blob/master/kavl.h)), this function (I think) is defined as follows:

```
#define __KAVL_INSERT(suf, __scope, __type, __head, __cmp) \
    __scope __type *kavl_insert_##suf(__type **root_, __type *x, unsigned *cnt_) { \
```

Later on in the kavl.h file there is this standalone line (line 322):

```
#define kavl_insert(suf, proot, x, cnt) kavl_insert_##suf(proot, x, cnt)
```

I don't have much technical knowledge with C (just learned parts as they were relevant), and I'm wondering how this works.  The casing is different, and there is the "__" precursor in the #define line.  How does this work?

Comment: It doesn't "work". As you noted, the casing and `__` are different. There must be an actual `kavl_insert` defined somewhere.

Comment: I took a look and found something sort of like that.  Is there a connection between the __KAVL_INSERT and kavl_insert?

Comment: Not in the code that you've shown. Maybe `kavl_insert_nei2` (that is, `kavl_insert_##suf` with `suf = nei2`) calls it, maybe not.

Comment: What does the "__scope __type" mean here?  I was thinking if there was a connection it would be there, but it seems not

Comment: `__scope` and `__type` are the parameters of the macro. Judging by the name, `__type` is the return type (here `*` is always added to the type), but to be certain you have to see how the macro is called.

Comment: All of those identifiers starting with `__` are reserved for use by the C compiler and standard library. I suppose that the code happens to work for now on the compilers they have used, but it's undefined behaviour and could fail at any time. Please do not take it as good programming style. It isn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first `__KAVL_INSERT` macro is used to declare functions which all start with the same prefix (`kavl_insert_`) and end with the specified suffix (parameter `suf`).

So, when you see this:

```
__KAVL_INSERT(foo, static, int, null, null)
```

preprocessor will replace it with a function with the appropriate name, scope, and parameter types:

```
static int *kavl_insert_foo(int **root_, int *x, unsigned *cnt_) { \
    /* actual function body ... */ \
    /* with lots of trailing backshashes ... */ \
    /* because it's the only way to create ... */ \
    /* a multiline macro in C */ \
}
```

The lowercase `kavl_insert` macro, on the other hand:

```
kavl_insert(foo, &something, &whatever, 0);
```

simply expands to the actual function call, i.e. it's equivalent to calling the function defined above:

```
kavl_insert_foo(&something, &whatever, 0);
```

The idea behind this kind of macros is usually to create a generic type-safe data structure in C, using the preprocessor, like the [klib](https://github.com/attractivechaos/klib) library of various generic data structures.

Comment: Thank you for your reply!  To clarify, how does the preprocessor know to replace `__KAVL_INSERT` with a function with the appropriate name, scope, and parameter types?  Is it because of the line following, `__scope __type *kavl_insert__##suf(...)`?  Also, what you wrote, `static int *kavl_insert_foo(int **root_, ...)`, is it a more generalized form of what is here, `__scope __type *kavl_insert_##suf(__type **root_,...)`?  And finally, to clarify, is `kavl_insert(foo...)` what is called in the code, and it iself expands to the above-defined `_KAVL_INSERT` `static int *kavl_insert_foo(...)`?

Comment: @Chris: double hash sign (`##`) tells the preprocessor to concatenate two strings, so `kavl_insert_##suf` means "append the `suf` parameter passed to the macro to the `kavl_insert_` string. If you use the `-E` parameter with gcc (you can check this with the [godbolt online compiler](https://godbolt.org/z/77n3TP)), you can see how the preprocessed file looks like before the compilation stage. Left pane in the linked webpage shows the source code, right pane shows the final result for gcc 8.2 with `-E`.

Comment: The reason klib is doing all this might become apparent if you decide to write your own generic data structure. For example, a vector-like data structure is very usable in C (a struct which contains a pointer to an array, its capacity and its current length, and automatically  increases the capacity as needed). If you wanted to pass around a list of `int` vectors, or `char` vectors, or a vector of any custom structs, you would have to copy all the functions over and over again (or use `char*`/`void*` and then cast all around the code, which makes the code prone to runtime mistakes).

Comment: Is the `kavl_insert(foo, ...)` connected to `__KAVL_INSERT(foo,...)`, and if so, how?  Sorry if I'm missing something.  It looks to me that `KAVL_INSERT(foo...)` declaring functions that start with `kavl_insert_` would exclude `kavl_insert', as it lacks that last underscore.

Comment: @Chris: have you checked the link above? Which underscore does it lack? `__KAVL_INSERT(suf...` creates the function *declaration* `kavl_insert_suf`. Then `kavl_insert(suf...` creates the function *invocation* `kavl_insert_suf`. One of them is a function definition/declaration, the second one is the invocation, but the concatenated name is equal in both cases. Perhaps [this example](https://godbolt.org/z/bxn8vr) is a bit clearer? Or [this example](https://godbolt.org/z/14Tfvf), which might better demonstrate the reason this is done in practice.

Comment: I've gone through more thoroughly with the examples you provided.  I think I see the logic here!  Thank you so much, I appreciate your help and examples!  This is much more clear to me now.

Comment: I notice if you call it via __KAVL_INSERT, you explicate the typing, ie `static int *kavl_insert_a(...)` vs if you call via kavl_insert(foo,...), in which case the result is just `kavl_insert_a(...)`.  What is the difference here?  I say that cause in the __KAVL_INSERT .h file, the function is written out as: `#define __KAVL_INSERT(suf, __scope, __type, __head, __cmp) \
 __scope __type *kavl_insert_##suf(__type **root_, __type *x, unsigned *cnt_) { \
  unsigned char stack[KAVL_MAX_DEPTH]; \
  __type *path[KAVL_MAX_DEPTH]; \ ...` for example, and it seems declaring __type is important

Comment: @Chris: this is true for any function in C; when you declare it, you must specify its type, name and parameters (and optionally scope if you don't want default `extern`). For example, [`strcpy`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcpy) for copying strings is defined as `char *strcpy( char *dest, const char *src );` (note the return type and parameter types), but when you're calling it from your code, you will simply call `strcpy(dest, src)`. The idea here is that you only place `__KAVL_INSERT` somewhere **once** to define the function, then you can call `kavl_insert` multiple times.

Comment: I've been looking through the code itself some more, and playing with godbolt, and here is what I mean:  We write something like #define `_X(y) void x_##y(void)` happens, and then at some later point we write `_X(a)`, so now the function `x_a(void)` is declared.  We then write `#define x(y) x_##y()`.  Can we call something like `x(b)` now?  It seems like a function is defined when we call `_X(b)` with its typing and such, but it doesn't seem to be called if we just write `x(b)`, in this case; edit: like when calling `x(b)`, it doesn't seem like a type is ever declared for the fxn `x_b(void)`

Comment: If you want to call `x_b`, you need to declare it somewhere using `_X(b)`, yes. If you need the `x_type` function for a specific type, you want to emit its entire source code through the preprocessor using the `_X` macro. I believe the best way to fully understand the concept is to try designing something like a dynamic array yourself. Go through [this quick example](https://godbolt.org/z/5818fG) and, once you understand what's going on, think of how you would reuse this code so that you can have a list of `float` or a list of `struct something`, like [this](https://godbolt.org/z/Gnec6W).

Comment: I will go through these more thoroughly, but I think I'm getting a better grasp overall.  I appreciate all of the examples and website suggestion (godbolt)!